# AWS Neptune with NLB and API Gateway + VPC Link

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-neptune, network-load-balancer

I am trying to access AWS Neptune Database from outside VPC (from laptop) with path User -> API Gateway -> VPC Link -> Private Network Load Balancer -> Neptune.

It is similar to the one mentioned below (for RDS).
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/access-amazon-rds-across-vpcs-using-aws-privatelink-and-network-load-balancer/

But I get the message : {"message":"Service Unavailable"}.

Security groups : Neptune SG allows ingress on 8182 from SG of NLB

Target group : on TCP 8182 (shows 1 target healthy)

API in API Gateway : route /sparql on method ANY with integration to NLB with VPC Link

Can you please suggest what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Neptune is not currently a supported service using [AWS `PrivateLink`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html).

Comment: Hello Taylor, I used VPCLink with API Gateway.  Can you please guide on how to implement it (may be an alternate)? I read your comments on and seems there are options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370652/how-can-an-aws-neptune-graph-be-queried-via-public-http/72370837#comment135568849_72370837